# Laravel/Postgres db queries?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I have (weird) problem with query on Laravel/Postgres DB Queries. I will paste entire query here(it's little too long but we will focus on just one part of it):

```
select distinct "products".*, "brands"."name" as "brand", "brands"."image" as "brand_image", "product_categories"."name" as "category", "product_categories"."slug" as "category_slug", count(distinct product_features.feature_category_id) as features_count from "products" inner join "brands" on "products"."brand_id" = "brands"."id" inner join "product_categories" on "products"."category_id" = "product_categories"."id" left join "product_features" on "products"."id" = "product_features"."product_id" where "products"."deleted_at" is null and "products"."category_id" in (142) and "products"."published" = true and "brands"."published" = true and "product_categories"."published" = true and "product_categories"."deleted_at" is null and "price" >= 0 and "price" <= 19000 and "products"."brand_id" in (17) and 
            (product_features.feature_category_id = 555 and
            CAST(product_features.value AS BOOLEAN) = true and
            product_features.deleted_at IS NULL) or
            (product_features.feature_category_id = 554 and
            CAST(product_features.value AS BOOLEAN) = true and
            product_features.deleted_at IS NULL) group by "products"."id", "brands"."name", "brands"."image", "product_categories"."name", "product_categories"."slug" having count(distinct product_features.feature_category_id) = 2 order by price asc
```

This is initial query but when I execute it I get weird error said:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "800"
```

I have no idea why is this error thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Your `product_features.value` is a text field. While Postgres is OK casting all nonzero integers like `800` to boolean `true`, it is not OK with casting `text` like `'800'` to `boolean`.

Solution is to check `product_features.value` on emptiness and/or equality to `'0'` instead of `CAST(product_features.value AS BOOLEAN) = true`.